# Is there a really fast way to switch between QWERTY and Dvorak?

Tags: keyboard-layout, dvorak, qwerty

What is the fastest way to switch between QWERTY and Dvorak on a Windows 7 Pro machine, by say, a key combination?

Comment: A different approach, which may or may not be suitable for your suituation, is to use [a keyboard that has a physical Dvorak/QWERTY switch](http://superuser.com/questions/396983/are-there-any-keyboards-available-with-a-physical-qwerty-dvorak-switch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is!

Launch `Control Panel` > `Region and Language` > Click the `Keyboards and Languages` tab, then the `Change keyboards....` button.

From here, click the `Advanced Key Settings` tab and you can set a shortcut for switching input keyboards.

[image]